The number of real roots of the equation $\displaystyle 1+\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots \cdots +\frac{x^{2012}}{2012}=0$

The number of real roots of the equation $\displaystyle 1+\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots \cdots +\frac{x^{2012}}{2012}=0$

What I try : Let $
$\displaystyle f(x)=1+\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{x^{2012}}{2012}.$
Then  $\displaystyle f'(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots +x^{2011}$
And for maxima and minima put $f'(x)=0$
Then from above equation $x=1$ is not a root of that equation
So we have
$\displaystyle \frac{x^{2012}-1}{x-1}=0\Longrightarrow x^{2012}=1$
We get $\displaystyle x=\bigg(1\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2012}}$
Also $\displaystyle f''(x)=1+2x+3x^2+\cdots +2011x^{2010}$
And at $\displaystyle f''\bigg((1)^{1/2012}\bigg)>0$
So minimum of $f(x)$ occur at $x=(1)^{1/2012}$
I.e no real solution occur.
Is my process is right , Please have a look
And if it is wrong , please explain me right solution. Thanks

In my opinion it's right.

You could say in the end that $f(1^{1/2012}) > 0$ for consistency.

By showing that $f(-1) > 0$, your argument will be complete.
One approach is to use Taylor's theorem, which gives $\ln 2 = f(-1) + \frac{1}{2013(1-c)^{2013}} (-1)^{2013}$ for some $c$ with $-1 \le c \le 0$.

Right, I didn't notice that also $f'(-1) = 0$
